# Вопрос о слове "поллитра"

Tags: орфоэпия

Написал в одном стихотворном тексте примерно следующее *"...соединим свои поллитры, // и с тем отправимся во двор, // решим в песочнице наш спор"*. Более полный контекст не хочу давать без нужды по личным мотивам и ни коим образом не претендую на разговор о самом стихе. Могу только добавить, что подразумевалось стилизация под дворовую поэзию.

Редактор (не штатный, друг хороший) исправил на *пол-литры*. Я согласился, не придавая этому никакого значения. 
Но все-таки интересно, что вы думаете о существовании такого слова  (поллитра, поллитры, поллитре, ... о поллитрах)? Дефисное написание - это немного другое слово получается по семантике даже. А нормативное (по Лопатину)  *полулитра* - стилистически не то.

Поллитра - это не объем, это счетная единица, универсальная конвертируемая валюта советского периода...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> что вы думаете о существовании такого слова (поллитра, поллитры, поллитре, ... о поллитрах)?

А что тут думать: если его употребляют, значит, существует. даже в словарях зафиксировано, правда, ненормативных (оно ж ненормативное), например, в Большом словаре русских поговорок [ПОЛЛИТРА (ПОЛ-ЛИТРА) | enc-dic.com](http://enc-dic.com/russaying/Pollitra-pol-litra-43518.html), в Историческом словаре галлицизмов русского языка [поллитра | academic.ru](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/30483/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0) И примеры там есть:

ПОЛЛИТРА ы, ж. То же, что поллитровка. - Так я "Рояль" пью. Три тысячи бутылка. Пять поллитр. По шестьсот рублей. И все путем. 1993. Ю. Крелин Потапыч и Исакыч. //Знамя 1994 10 157.

И вот на тебе - враг на Волге, под Москвой, под Ленинградом, половины страны и армии как корова языком слизнула, кто кого доламывает - попробуй разберись без поллитры. В. Астафьев Прокляты и убиты. // НМ 1992 10 68.

И даже у Ожегова есть добавочка - разговорное написание [HTTP://OZHEGOV.INFO/SLOVAR/?EX=Y&Q=%D0ПОЛ-ЛИТРА](http://HTTP://OZHEGOV.INFO/SLOVAR/?EX=Y&Q=%D0%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9B-%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%90)
м. (согласуется так же, как полметра). 1. (полулитра и разг. поллитра).

Если есть ЛИТРА ([ЛИТРА | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_6537)

ЛИТРА, -ы, ЛИТРА, -ы, ЛИТРУХА, -и, ж. Литровая бутылка спиртного.
), почему не может быть поллитры?...

Думаю, что зря Вам исправили, в стилизации под дворовую поэзию нормальное слово.

Comment: А проблема-то была больше в орфографии, чем в  в сушествовании.

Answer (score 1):

> *...соединим свои поллитры*
>
> Редактор (не штатный, друг хороший) исправил на *пол-литры.*

Редактор прав: ***пол-литра*** и в значении ***половина литра***, и в значении ***поллитровка*** в [***"Русском орфографическом словаре"***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB*%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&all=x)  пишется одинаково  — через дефис.

.

Ну а в книгах можно встретить и дефисное, и слитное написание, причём у одного и того же автора в одном  и том же произведении.

[**У Астафьева, изданного в 1994 году:**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vNUXAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%22%20%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%22%20%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzu-2Mi-7LAhVFiSwKHTaGCxcQ6AEIKjAD)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[**У него же, но уже в 1997 году:**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=dSdgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%22%20%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%22%20%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGoeXqiu7LAhWKDiwKHYgVDywQ6AEIGzAA)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря ненормативной лексики (2002)

**Пол-литра,** **м,** прост. То же, что поллитровка. Подруга вышла как раз из лавки **с пол-литром** (Е. Дорош. Деревенский дневник). **Без пол-литра** не разберешься (шутл.)

Получается, что здесь при образовании просторечного слова "поллитра" женского рода  (И.п., 1-е скл., слитное написание) за образец взяли   слово "пол-литра" (мужского рода, вторая часть сложного слова в форме Р.п.), при этом изменилась и грамматика, и орфография.

Примеры:

А вот и еще один. И тоже с **поллитром**. [Семен Лунгин. Виденное наяву (1989-1996)].

После нашего разговора о «Нюшке» Смеляков поехал в ЦК, потом позвонил мне ― уже с дачи. ― Приезжай, но только **с поллитрой**. С тебя причитается. [Евгений Евтушенко. «Волчий паспорт» (1999)]

И терпения не хватит, и друзья **с поллитрой** отыщут. [В. Лихоносов. Люблю тебя светло (1968)].

**Вывод (этапы изменения слова)**

**(1) Пол-литра, м (мера объема) - (2) пол-литра, м (поллитровка) - (3) поллитра (поллитром), м - (4) поллитра (поллитрой), ж.**  Хотя дефисное написание считается орфографически правильным, оно правильно для первого слова, а переход 2 - 3,4  вполне закономерен, так как это уже не сложное слово с корнем ПОЛ, а сущ. м. и ж. рода, хотя и просторечные.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, тут от смысла зависит. Людмила все сказала по сути, только по моим ощущениям тонкость может быть. По вашему определению бутылка с водкой, упаковка, в стеклянной таре - скорее *пол-литра*. А счетная единица - *поллитра*. Посмотрите в примерах у Людмилы.

У вас просматривается смысл первого, "поднимем бокалы, содвинем их разом", так ведь? Тогда редактор прочувствовал лучше.

Answer (score 0):

*Поллитра* в рассматриваемом случае - самостоятельная сущность, а не просто *половина литра*: в тексте не сказано, о чем именно в объеме 500 мл идет речь, но это и так понятно. Если заменить на, скажем, *полметра*, предложение не будет иметь законченного смысла:

*— Вынеси полметра!* (Полметра чего?)

Самостоятельность и неподобность прочим словам на *пол* усиливается множественным числом: для *"полметра", "пол-лимона"* и т. д. оно вообще было бы невозможно, вероятно, по причине отсутствия рода. А что *поллитр*, что *поллитра*, как свободно склоняемые в значении "бутылка водки", род однозначно имеют (хотя, строго говоря, это означает, что *дай поллитра* - грамматически неверно: либо *дай поллитру*, либо *дай поллитр*; но тут уже очевидно влияние собственно *"пол-литра"* - омонима со значением "половины литра", требующим явного или следующего из контекста указания, половины литра чего).

Поэтому писать через дефис в данном случае нет оснований.

Comment: А о чём речь? О водке? Каждый по пол-литра выпивает?

Comment: А на мой взгляд, говорить "поллитр" (м. р.) неверно.

Comment: Конечно, о водке. Вот и вы сразу догадались.
Насчет того, верно или неверно, - выше приведен минимум один пример из художественной литературы с "поллитром". Просто в именительном падеже единственного числа это слово обычно не употребляется.

Comment: Хаха, но по пол-литра (или поллитре) что-то многовато. ;)

Comment: До дна допивать никто не неволит. Но из исходного поста, где говорится об "универсальной валюте советского периода", однозначно следует, что речь о водке.